# Rotate a Material UI LinearProgress

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, rotation

I'm trying to make a graph chart with Material UI using the `LinearProgress` component with some styling the basic idea is to get this to rotate `90deg`

```
const BorderLinearProgressBottom = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  colorPrimary: {
    backgroundColor:
      theme.palette.grey[theme.palette.type === "light" ? 200 : 700],
  },
  bar: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#00A99E",
  },
  transform: [{ rotate: "90deg" }],
}))(LinearProgress);
```

gets my

```
 <BorderLinearProgressBottom
     variant="determinate"
     value={22}
     />
```

to look like this

[image]

How can I get it to rotate by `90deg`?

I tried putting in the `BorderLinearProgressBottom` `transform: [{ rotate: "90deg" }],` but that did not work.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-75snq?file=/demo.js:672-855)

Comment: If you could please share a working example of your code then it would be little bit easier for other people to help.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-75snq?file=/demo.js:672-855

Comment: Maybe, [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-zoku6?file=/demo.js) could help.

Comment: @JunaidFaryad almost.. any way to get the blue on the bottom?

Comment: You mean move the bars to the bottom? Sorry, Could you please explain a little more?

Comment: got it! "rotate(270deg)" works. you can post the answer what you did so I can mark it

Comment: @dovigz use `rotate(-90deg)` instead of `270deg`. But using `transform` will break your layout anyway, you should have a look at how the `Slider` component works (it can be displayed vertically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use `rotate(-90deg)` if you want to display the `LinearProgress` vertically, it will break your layout because `transform` only scales the element visually without changing the size, so a rotated `LinearProgress` still occupies the space as if it's laid out horizontally. To rotate both its appearance and size, you should have a look at the implementation of [`Slider`](https://mui.com/components/slider/#vertical-sliders) for reference. But I'll write it down for you now to save time.

First off you need to swap the `height` and `width` of the `ProgressBar` container:

```
// before
height: 50, // restrict the height
width: 'auto', // expand as long as you want (inside container)

// after
width: 50, // restrict the width
height: '100%', // expand as high as you want (inside container)
```

Then rotate the progress bar inside. This `transform` works because it only transforms 'locally' (the bar position is absolute inside the container).

```
bar: {
  // the default style uses translateX, so we need to switch the axis
  transform: ({ value }) => {
    return `translateY(${value}%) !important`;
  }
}
```

And that's it. You're done. Not it will look like a vertical `Slider`.

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thanks now I understand why my transform: "rotate(90deg)" was not working inside the bar

Comment: how would I show a date underneath the graph if the styling is pushing it upto the top?

Comment: @dovigz see my updated answer and the codesandbox demo. Change the height to `100%`  (turned out setting to `auto` is a bad idea).  and put it inside a flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how the same works in material-ui v5. First create a styled component:

```
const VerticalLinearProgress = styled(LinearProgress)(() => ({
  width: "16px",
  height: "100%",
  [`& .${linearProgressClasses.bar}`]: {
    backgroundColor: "#F5F6FA"
  },
  [`&.${linearProgressClasses.colorSecondary}`]: {
    backgroundColor: "#eb82bf"
  }
}));
```

Then you need to apply the progress as `value` and `sx` transform as follows:

```
const progress = 40

<VerticalLinearProgress
   variant="determinate"
   color="secondary"
   value={progress}
   sx={{
     [`& .${linearProgressClasses.bar}`]: {
       transform: `translateY(${-progress}%)!important`
     }
   }}
 />
```

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-hill-nwlnq2?file=/src/App.js:366-626)